# How can I avoid "auto-update" cache when using `react-apollo-hooks` and `useSubscription` hook

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-cache-inmemory

I have some **Apollo-Hooks** code that uses `useSubscription` to listen for event changes in a subscription:

```
useSubscription<MySubscriptionUpdated>(MySubscription, {
    onSubscriptionData: async ({ client, subscriptionData: { data } }) => {
      if (!data) {
        return;
      }
      ...
```

This code automatically updates the cache on the response, which is great in most circumstances

However, I need to do some result-processing *after* the response is received, yet *prior* to the cache being updated.

*Does anyone know of a way to use `useSubscription` hook, and **not** have the cache be automatically updated?*

The response will ultimately always have an entity with `__typename` in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change `fetchPolicy` for each subscription. The default value is `cache-first`. To disable cache must set fetchPolicy to `no-cache`. For get more detail see [apollo official document](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-apollo/#optionsfetchpolicy).

```
useSubscription<MySubscriptionUpdated>(MySubscription, {
    fetchPolicy: "no-cache",
    onSubscriptionData: async ({ client, subscriptionData: { data } }) => {
      if (!data) {
        return;
      }
      ...
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you can do a manual cache update, it would look something like this

```
apollo.mutate({
  mutation: createTaskMutation,
  variables: item,
  update: (cache, { data }) => {
    try {
      let { allTasks } = cache.readQuery({ query: getTasks });
      allTasks.push(data);
      cache.writeQuery({ //
        query: getTasks,
        data: {
            'allTasks': allTasks
        }
      });
    } catch (e) {
        // We should always catch here,
        // as the cache may be empty or the query may fail
    }
});
```

Comment: Even when you use an `update` function, Apollo does an auto-update before calling your `update` unless you use `fetchPolicy: 'no-cache'`.  OP was asking how to prevent that auto-update.